# Google apps script - get A1 cell notation of each element in an array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that I want to search through a given sheet and return an array of cells containing the custom function "POPULATE". The function currently returns a string array of each instance of  "=POPULATE".

```
function formulaSearch() {
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('test');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();

  // Search for all cells with the POPULATE function and put them into array
  var cells = [];
  for (var row in formulas) {
    for (var col in formulas[row]) {
      if (formulas[row][col].indexOf("=POPULATE") > -1 ) {
        cells.push(formulas[row][col]);
        Logger.log(cells); 
      } 
    }
  }
  return cells;
}
```

How can I return an array of cells in A1 notation of each cell that contains the formula? I know of the .getA1Notation() method but I can't convert the elements in the returned array to the Range data type.

Comment: `formulas[row][col]` is just a `String` containing the cell's formula, not the actual cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to get the cell from the `range` variable and then get the A1 notation from that:

```
for (var row in formulas) {
  for (var col in formulas[row]) {
    if (formulas[row][col].indexOf("=POPULATE") > -1 ) {
      cell = range.getCell(row+1, col+1).getA1Notation();
      cells.push(cell);
      Logger.log(cells); 
    } 
  }
}
```

EDIT: Ranges are not 0 indexed. Added 1 to row and col in getCell(). Thanks for pointing that out @tsc333!

Comment: I'm getting the error message, "Cell reference out of range" referring to the line with the getCell() method.

Comment: Solution: since A1 notation isn't 0 indexed, I had to add 1 to each element in the row and col arrays and convert them into numbers by using `var rowNum=Number(row) + 1;` Then line 4 becomes `cell = range.getCell(rowNum, colNum).getA1Notation();`